# Back button not going to previous activity on the activity stack

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

I have an activity with a list view and in my OnListItemClick I am doing the following:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(WebViewContent));
intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);
intent.PutExtra ("ITEM_ID", t.ItemID.ToString());
intent.PutExtra ("ITEM_LINK", t.ItemLink.ToString());
intent.PutExtra ("ITEM_TYPE", t.ItemType.ToString());
StartActivity(intent);
```

In the new activity, the WebViewContent Activity I am doing this:           webView.SetWebViewClient(new AwesomeWebClient(this.dofinish));
 and in the doFinish, I start another activity like so:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(WebViewContent));
intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);
intent.PutExtra ("ITEM_ID", "7419");
intent.PutExtra ("ITEM_LINK", "");
intent.PutExtra ("ITEM_TYPE", "content");
StartActivity(intent);
```

BUT when I hit the back button, I do not go back to the previous activity, I go all the way back to the activity that first started.

I thought that each time I started a new activity it was stored on the activity stack and the back button always went to the previous on the stack.

Can someone help me understand why the back button is not doing what I am expecting?

Comment: it looks like it's due to the NewTask flag: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManagingTasks

Comment: Yes, quite possible and I have read through the link you specified but still no luck.  From reading the link it seems like I need the new task on the first activity, but not subsequent ones, but I am still having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation it's the NewTask flag you're using:

**[FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)**

> If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this
>   history stack. A task (from the activity that started it to the next
>   task activity) defines an atomic group of activities that the user can
>   move to. Tasks can be moved to the foreground and background; all of
>   the activities inside of a particular task always remain in the same
>   order. See Tasks and Back Stack for more information about tasks.
>
> This flag is generally used by activities that want to present a
>   "launcher" style behavior: they give the user a list of separate
>   things that can be done, which otherwise run completely independently
>   of the activity launching them.
>
> When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity
>   you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started;
>   instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the
>   screen with the state it was last in. See FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK
>   for a flag to disable this behavior.

Comment: So I set this flag like so: intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.MultipleTask); then start my activity in my OnListItemCLick.  But when I start the next activity the same thing happens.  I go the the list view, not back to the previous web view.

Comment: dont set the NewTask flag at all, omit it.